# React ignores value attribute of input field

Tags: reactjs, forms

I have a react sign-up form. I want to set up an input (checkbox) that holds the value as some text - e.g:

```
<form onSubmit={this.validateStepTwo} id="registerForm">
    <label htmlFor="short_bio">Tell the users a bit about yourself:</label>
    <input type="textarea" name="short_bio" className="textarea-small"/>

    <label htmlFor="bio_info">Tell the users who you are</label>
    <input type="textarea" name="bio_info" className="textarea-large"/>

    <label htmlFor="bio_exp">Tell the users what you did</label>
    <input type="textarea" name="bio_exp" className="textarea-large"/>

    <input type="checkbox" name="instructor" value="I want to be an instructor" />

    <input type="submit" value="Register" className="submit"></input>

    {this.state.errors !== null ? (
        <h1 className="error">{this.state.errors}</h1>
    ) : ('')}
</form>
```

Where

```
<input type="checkbox" name="instructor" value="I want to be an instructor" />
```

should have a value of "I want to be an instructor" but it doesnt have anything.

I tried doing it like this:

```
<input ...>I want to be an instructor</input>
```

but that threw another error.

Is this a react thing or am i missing something in my code? Ive been on the computer for 13 hours so i wouldnt be surprised if i made a dumb mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkbox input value is the one sent  in  the request and not the text that appears afterwards.

If you want it to be the text then do something like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="instructor" value="instructor"> I want to be an instructor
```

Comment: ohh yeah :/ I guess i forgot HTML xD